# How to incorporate local folder into an existing git repo?

Tags: git, github

Alright so I have local folder `training`, that contains a bunch of scripts. Also, my group has a repo on git, where I should incorporate my folder. I did some research and found the following:

```
git init
git add <folder1> <folder2> <etc.>
git commit -m "Your message about the commit"
git remote add origin https://github.com/yourUsername/yourRepository.git
git push -u origin master
git push origin master
```

Unfortunately I don't have the url at the moment, but I already cloned the repository with `git clone`. What can I do?

Comment: This is creating a new git repository with only your data. If you want to add your folder to the existing repo, you should clone that repo, copy your folder into it, commit, and push.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 options for creating local git repository.

1. As you added on your question, you can use `git init` which creates a local repository on your computer, which you can later push to github server using `git remote`.
2. The second option, which is the one you used (without knowing) is cloning a project from github using `git clone`, which import the remote project onto your local machine. Later, after adding  to your local project, you can use `git add <folder>`, `git commit -m "adding <folder>"` and `git push` to send the folder to github servers. This is what you should do in your case.